# Returning a DataFrame from Series.apply when the supplied function returns a Series is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The way I have always split a column containing lists into multiple columns is:

```py
df['column_with_lists'].apply(pd.Series)
```

This returns a new dataframe that can then be concatenated.

With `pandas 2.1`, this now raises:

> `FutureWarning`: Returning a DataFrame from Series.apply when the supplied function returns a Series is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

What is now the recommended way to split a column containing lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) return a DataFrame is deprecated because :

> This pattern was very slow and it’s recommended to use alternative methods to archive the same goal. Check [*GH52116*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52116) for more details/context

You can for example do a *classical* construction like below to turn-off the `FutureWarning` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_with_lists": [range(4, 6), range(1, 5)]})

out = pd.DataFrame(df["column_with_lists"].tolist())
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   0  1      2      3
0  4  5    NaN    NaN
1  1  2 3.0000 4.0000
```

---

***UPDATE*** :

This deprecation was reverted in [`2.1.1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1.1/whatsnew/v2.1.1.html#other) released yesterday.

Comment: This is not equivalent to returning a nice Series in a function because the Series retains the index name - `.tolist()` does not.